# How to always reference the latest version of xml.xsd from W3C?

Tags: xml, xsd, versioning, xml-namespaces

Many XML schemas I use reference xml.xsd e.g. thus:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>
```

This `schemaLocation` value references a specific version of the XSD.

Is it possible to refer to the "the most recent version W3C's xml.xsd" rather than "this version" and going back to check for updates / aligning different schemas to the same version, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the ["Versioning policy for this schema document"](https://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd) section in that document, you will see that this policy is precisely what you ask for:

> The schema document at that URI may however change in the future, in
>   order to remain compatible with the latest version of XML Schema
>   itself, or with the XML namespace itself. In other words, if the XML
>   Schema or XML namespaces change, the version of this document at
>   http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd will change accordingly; the version at
>   http://www.w3.org/2009/01/xml.xsd will not change.

Comment: I read it again for the Xth time and I finally get what is going on. So, the version with the earliest date is of course the latest version. Makes perfect sense ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately W3C established the convention of putting the year in namespace URIs before they realised that it is often best to keep a namespace URI stable even when the underlying specification changes.